# Easiest way to transfer files online

Tags: c#, file-transfer

Hi im currently programming an application to sync videogamesaves between computers but i have run into a bit of a problem. I need to be able to upload my save file to a cloud or send it using an email or something similar. I'm not a experienced programmer so i'm looking for a simple option if there is one.

I basically have everything up to this point all i need is a function that accepts a Path and then uploads the file found there.

Any help or tipps are appreciated :)

Comment: So what shall it be? An email or upload to cloud? If cloud what cloud service do you want to use? We cant really decide that for you.

Comment: Maybe we can give him options. Replying in a moment.

Comment: Yeah im basically looking to be advised :)

Comment: Install onedrive/googledrive/dropbox or whatever then you can just save to a local directory the client do the upload/sync for you automatically.

Comment: Do you even need a sync functionality, cant it stay online and the users access it online? Do you really want it to be synced automatically with a local source?

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the tip but im really looking to use code to do it so i can get a base understanding of how it works and then build on that.

Comment: @RandRandom it does need to be synced because the savegame will be changed after every use.

Comment: Accepting answer is a good behavior :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options to achieve the "send data from my computer to a centralized server" task. It depends on your knowledge, security you want to achieve, technologies you can-want adopt and other factors.

Since you're saying you're inexperienced I also assume you don't need a high grade of security, so for the sake of argument I'm just giving a suggestion, maybe an idea for a proof-of-concept. Take it with this spirit in mind.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to put a web page online, on a web server, and post data to it. Sending data from .NET is really easy using a WebClient instance; on the other side you can publish a simple web page, using Microsoft technologies but really whatever you want (PHP on a cheap web space) and catch what have been POSTed.

If you're going to explore this solution, consider investing in a security certificate that can encrypt your connection via HTTPS: this is a simple solution, also simply hackable. At least HTTPS can help you a bit in this sense.

Comment: That would work but the thing is this project is mainly a leanring experience for me. im not really looking to spend money on a server or webspace.

Comment: You can obtain a free web space then, or run a local instance of a web server

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the local Dropbox Sny cand go from there maybe expanding to a web service.